# Comparar o número de ocorrências de um Array em campos dinâmicos JavaScript antes de enviar os dados do formulário

Tags: php, javascript

Como posso comparar o número de ocorrências do *Array* em campos dinâmicos *JavaScript* antes de enviar os dados do formulário. Preciso verificar se ambos são iguais. Consigo fazer apenas depois do envio com a função *count* do *PHP*, mais gostaria de saber se há como fazer antes do envio, e se possível, via *JavaScript*, pois já é a validação do formulário. Como contar esses valores do *Array* antes do envio?

Campos dinâmicos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Verificar se ambos Array tem o mesmo número de ocorrências 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mail_form").submit( function() {

        var qtdmyfoto = document.querySelectorAll('name="myfoto[]"').length;
        var qtdreferencia = document.querySelectorAll('name="referencia[]"').length;

        if(qtdmyfoto != qtdreferencia)
        {
        alert("Falta alguma coisa");
        return false;
        }   

    });

});
</script>

<form id="mail_form" role="form" action="">
       .
       .
       .
       .
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
       .
       .
       .
       .
   $(wrapper).append('<div>'
        +'<div>'
            +'<br><label class="control-label">Foto: '+z +'</label>'
            +'<input type="file"  name="myfoto[]"  /> '
        +'</div>'

        +'<div>'
            +'<br><label class="control-label">Referência Foto '+z +'</label>'
            +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="referencia[]">'
        +'</div>'    
    +'</div>');
    </script>
</form>
```

Estou tentando sem sucesso algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mail_form").submit( function() {

        if(referencia.array.length != myfoto.array.length)
        {
            alert("Falta alguma coisa");
            return false;
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Não sabemos o que é a variável `myfoto` nem `referencia`... podes explicar? Será que queres saber quantos elementos `name="myfoto[]"` há? Nesse caso `var qtd = document.querySelectorAll('name="myfoto[]"').length;`

Comment: myfoto[] = Imagem - referencia[] = string Vou testar isso.

Comment: Não precebi o que queres dizer com `myfoto[] = Imagem - referencia[] = string`. Podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar mais informação?

Comment: Conseguiste o que querias? queres verificar se há _n_ elementos na página ou se eles têm valor atribuído?

Comment: Não consegui. Quero comparar se os arrays são iguais. (Mesma quantidade)

Comment: E não estás a conseguir comparar? Algum erro na consola? ou o submit não é cancelado?

Comment: Vou testar melhor amanhã e te dou o retorno, me enrolei com outra coisa, obrigado por enquanto @Sergio

Comment: Não consegui comparar o número de ocorrências entre os arrays. Por hora resolvi validando todos os campos para não serem vazios. $("#mail_form").validate(); <input required>. Obrigado a ajuda @Sergio